# JProfiler GUI on 32 bit machine connecting to 64bit server

Tags: jprofiler

I am profiling a java process which is running on 64 bit JVM on a linux box, I cant launch a GUI on that linux box.

When i connect from my 32 bit windows box i get error 
JProfiler> ERROR: another application or a different
JProfiler> version of JProfiler tried to connect.

Is it that i need a 64 bit machine to connect to the remote 64 bit machine and get the profiling details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the same version of JProfiler for the profiling agent (on the remote Linux box) and the JProfiler GUI (on your local Windows machine).

The "bitness" of the profiling agent does not matter.